# Are there any words that are pronounced differently if you add prefixes?

Tags: pronunciation

I know a couple of words that the main part is pronounced differently if you add prefixes(in-, un-, re-...) to it.
 I was just wondering if there is any other words?

Comment: Yes. EXTRA + ORDINARY, and EXTRAORDINARY, the latter of which is pronounced ĭk-strôr′dn-ĕr′ē.

Comment: "I know a couple of words that the main part is pronounced differently if you add prefixes" So which words are they? We don't know what "other" words if we don't know which you already know....

Comment: I've a feeling this has been discussed here before

Comment: famous, infamous. There are a bunch

Comment: Please edit your question to say which ones you were thinking of. Does *renaissance* count?

Answer (score 1):

Meter; perimeter.  Thesis, antithesis